# Tests failling to include Cakesession when using Taggable Plugin

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

(using CakePHP 1.3, and the Taggable plugin.)

Fails while running my tests with error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'CakeSession' not found in app/plugins/tags/models/behaviors/taggable.php on line 137
```

In my test I'm including **fixtures** like this:

```
var $fixtures = array('app.tag','app.tagged'); //including others
```

However, **it works fine** when I use the baked version:

```
var $fixtures = array('app.plugin.tags.tag','app.plugin.tags.tagged');
```

The problem with this being that it's now using Test fixtures from the plugins test folder. Now, **I could** add my fixtures there and be done with it, but that doesn't seem right.

Plugin fixtures(that are specific for my app) should work from my app/tests directory, no?

**UPDATE**: actually, just noticed that my default Plugin test cases are also failing with the same error, so I'm looking into that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that Taggable uses Session information which is not set during tests. In my test cases I set the user id manually with the following code, and it works now:

```
App::import('Component', 'Session');
$Session = new SessionComponent();
$Session->write('Auth.User', array(
    'id' => 1
));
```

Comment: Instead of using the `SessionComponent` in the tests you should just use `CakeSession` directly. `App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource'); CakeSession::wirte('Auth.User', array(...));`

Comment: I'm using CakePHP 1.3 so that snippet doesn't work for me. Any reason why the code I use isn't ok?

Comment: It is OK. What @dogmatic69 referred to is that you could you the CakeSession directly, but you're fine the way you're going.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification :) He said *should* so I thought I was doing it wrong. Thanks!

Comment: `should` because Components are meant for controllers, not tests, shells or any other place. You _can_ use SessionComponent just like you _can_ use `session_start()` and `$_SESSION`